# What is the difference between american sort and radix sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

I came across this sorting algorithm called american sort. I read it being a variant of radix sort. Can someone elaborate me regarding this sorting algorithm and also the time and space complexity related to it.

Comment: Is this it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_flag_sort

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the [American flag sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_flag_sort), an efficient, *in-place* variant of radix sort that distributes items into hundreds of buckets. It is a *Distribution Sort*: where items are distributed from the input to multiple intermediate structures (buckets in this case), which are then gathered and placed on the output.

---

**Radix sort**: Time: O(nk), Space: O(n+k), `n` is the number of keys, `k` is the maximum number of digits a number (value) can have.

**American flag sort**: Time: O(n*k/d), Space: O(k), `n` is the number of digits and `k` is the average bucket size.

---

Read more in [american flag sort optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262797/american-flag-sort-optimization).

Read [Engineering Radix Sort (1993)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6990), where in the paper experimental comparison is presented between the two algorithms.

A Java [implementation](https://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/sorts/AmericanFlagSort.java) of American Flag Sort.

Comment: `Space: In-place` doesn't account for `counts` and `offsets` arrays, they are presumably `O(k)`, if `k` is radix or the number of buckets.

Answer (score 0):

American flag sort is much more complicated than key-indexed counting radix sort. Instead of using an auxiliary array of length N to store the sorted result and then writing back to the original array. It directly writes back to original array by the computed offset.
For each item it writes back, the affcted item in original array needs to write to it's final position first while that process can affect more items, you need to write them back cyclically.
Refer to [AmericanFlagSort.java](https://github.com/phishman3579/java-algorithms-implementation/blob/master/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/sorts/AmericanFlagSort.java) to understand the algorithm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).